# AzureAD - MS Graph - New-MgApplicationOwnerByRef Powershell cmd-let problem

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-ad-graph-api

I am preparing automation for Azure Entra ID (Azure AD) service. I need to add SPN to Ownets of this Registered Application (pls see the screenshot).

[image]

From Azure Portal GUI there is no option to do it, but using Powershell and older AzureAD module I was able to do it, AzureAD module will be deprecated soon so I have to use Microsoft.Graph. In Ms documentation I can find the command `New-MgApplicationOwnerByRef`, but I am not sure what IDs I have to pass here, code from documentation below:

```
$NewOwner = @{
  "@odata.id"= "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{075b32dd-edb7-47cf-89ef-f3f733683a3f}"
  }

New-MgApplicationOwnerByRef -ApplicationId 'f6b30057-7095-4e2c-89f8-224149f591b7' -BodyParameter $NewOwner
```

What ID should I put in `"@odata.id"`, is it SPN object ID? What should be passed to the parameter `-ApplicationId` ?

I am facing an error, below see the screenshot, I am using SPN, API permissions on the screenshot.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add service principal as **Owner** of Azure AD app registration, you can run below PowerShell script:

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Applications
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Application.ReadWrite.All"

$params = @{
    "@odata.id" = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/spObjId/"
}

$applicationId = "appregObjId"
New-MgApplicationOwnerByRef -ApplicationId $applicationId -BodyParameter $params
```

**Response:**

[image]

To confirm that, I checked the same in Portal where service principal added as **owner** of app registration successfully as below:

[image]

In your case, you need to pass **SPN object ID** for `"@odata.id"` that can be found in *Enterprise Applications* as below:

[image]

For `-ApplicationId` parameter, you need to pass **Object ID** of App registration that can be found here:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

To avoid user interaction, you can connect to MS Graph as a **service principal** by passing client secret credentials.

I registered one Azure AD application and granted **`Application.ReadWrite.All`** permission as below:

[image]

Now, create once **client secret** and include it in below modified script to connect as a service principal:

```
$ClientId = "appId"
$TenantId = "tenantId"
$ClientSecret = "secret"
$ClientSecretPass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $ClientSecret -AsPlainText -Force
$ClientSecretCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $ClientId, $ClientSecretPass

Connect-MgGraph -TenantId $TenantId -ClientSecretCredential $ClientSecretCredential

Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Applications
$params = @{
    "@odata.id" = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/spObjId/"
}

$applicationId = "AppObjId"
New-MgApplicationOwnerByRef -ApplicationId $applicationId -BodyParameter $params
```

**Response:**

[image]

In Portal, service principal will be assigned as **Owner** of Azure AD app registration.

Comment: OK, thanks for your hints, but I dont want to use interactive commands "Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Application.ReadWrite.All", I need to put this solution into to powershell script linked with scheduler, it should work without any user interactions.

Comment: You can also connect to MS Graph via **service principal** without any user Interaction by running `Connect-MgGraph -TenantId $TenantId -ClientSecretCredential $ClientSecretCredential`. Refer this [link](https://bonguides.com/how-to-connect-to-graph-powershell-with-a-client-secret/#:~:text=How%20to%20Connect%20to%20Graph%20PowerShell%20with%20a,%40params%20-AccountEnabled%20-PasswordProfile%20%24passwordProfile%20...%203%20Conclusion%20)

Comment: @tester81 Please check the updated answer

Comment: I tested all you mentioned, still getting an error, pls see the post update, I added error code and SPNs API permissions.

Comment: That error is not related to permissions. Could you include what Ids you passed for  `"@odata.id"` and `-ApplicationID`?

Comment: "@odata.id" = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/SPNObjectID/", -ApplicationId "RegisteredAppID"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255615/discussion-between-sridevi-and-tester81).